# Rails form get and post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement Ajax search. When the user enters the query into the text field, the data should display below it and if there are not results, a new entry should be created in the database.

I have a button next to the text field. When the user presses the button, the data in the text field should be posted to the create method which creates a new record in the database. How can I do that?

Now i am using this:

```
<%= form_tag song_requests_path, :method => 'get', :id => "requests_search", :class => 'well form-horizontal' do %>
                    <p>
                        <h2> I Love To Sing ...</h2>
                        <%= text_field_tag :search1, params[:search1], :class => 'text_field span4',:placeholder=>"Song Title", :maxlength => "250" %>
                        <%= text_field_tag :search2, params[:search2], :class => 'text_field span3', :placeholder=>"Album", :maxlength => "250" %>
                    </p>

                    <% end %>


<%=form_for(  :song_request, :remote => true)  do |f| %>


<center>
    <%= f.hidden_field :title, :value => "#{params[:search1]}" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :album, :value => "#{params[:search2]}" %>

    <%= f.submit " Request ", :class => 'btn btn-primary'%>
</center>
<%end%>
```

Functionally its working perfect, but i can't place the request button besides the text field...Thank u....

Comment: Have you tried anything? What didn't work exactly? Could you post the code that doesn't work? I'm afraid the question in its current from won't get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I wonder why you've created two forms! RoR 3.2 comes with Dynamic attribute-based finders `find_or_create_by_ATTR` [check this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).  Also the title of the question and content don't match. Do you want to find/create record when searched or place request button beside text field? Please reframe the question.